# chrome print to pdf doesn't work with files

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to print page from html file to pdf using chrome, but it doesn't work.
This is my command:

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf={absolute_path_to_output_file} {absolute_path_to_input_file}
```

Chrome finishes in 2 seconds, it doesn't show any error, but also it doesn't create output file.
Interestingly, when I change my path to input file to url for example https://google.com, the file is created and it works. Now, You can think that probably path to html file is wrong, but it isn't because when i erease --headless I see that browser open my file, but it does nothing more.

Comment: When you use the `file://` protocol prefix before the absolute path, does chrome create the output file?

Comment: No, I've tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I discovered what is wrong. Path to input file can't contain #, but output file can. I had directory c# in path.